# Problem with Hardhat reading a forked Ethereum Mainnet address - getting error in getSigners() function

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I created a forked mainnet off Ethereum mainnet using my alchemy address and created the fork using Hardhat, I was able to see the fake contracts in the forked mainnet.

I'm running the following code using Hardhat and ethers on my Visual Studio code:

//Lesson 61 - Connecting to Mainnet Fork

```
     it("Send a transaction / swaps a Token", async () => {
        //const hre = require("hardhat")

        //const hre = require("hardhat");
        //const assert = require("assert");
        const [ownerSigner] = await ethers.providers.getSigners();
        console.log(ownerSigner); //Not working..!!
```

});

> I ran npx hardhat test and I get the following error:

Read and Write to the Blockchain
✔ connects to a provider, factory, token, and a router
1937067327436140972299 This is amount.string
✔ Gets the Price of amountsOut (2639ms)
1) Send a transaction / swaps a Token

2 passing (3s)
1 failing

1. Read and Write to the Blockchain
   Send a transaction / swaps a Token:
   TypeError: ethers.providers.getSigners is not a function
   at Context. (C:\Users\User\flashloanTest\hardhatTest\test\sendSwapTX.js:86:58)
   at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

I've been struggling with this for a day now, any ideas please? High appreciate your help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error is `ethers.providers.getSigners is not a function`

Change it to:

ethers.provider.getSigner() => signer

ethers.getSiger() => signer

ethers.getSigners() => signer[]

Comment: I tried with this: 'const [ownerSigner] = await ethers.getSigners();' i get error: 1) Read and Write to the Blockchain
       Send a transaction / swaps a Token:
     TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function
      at new HardhatEthersSigner (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:73:30)
      at Function.create (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-

Comment: I tried this: 'const [ownerSigner] = await ethers.getSigners()' i get the following error: 1) Read and Write to the Blockchain
       Send a transaction / swaps a Token:
     TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function

Comment: Could you post your git repo? I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: Hi,Sure, here is my git repo - https://github.com/fuzzyshak/HardhatSwap/upload/main    note: I installed hardhat using npm, then I installed ethersJS using 'npm install ethers^5.7.2 as this is the best version that works with the code.

Comment: Here is a video showing the error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UoJLAfqV6m4r4HaF1MUAnRU2mm3k4w-A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for late reply, you have a lot of dev dependencies 
Btw, If you don't like ethers 6 and want to use ethers 5.7.2. Don't try to use hardhat 2.10.x and install ethers 5 separately. Just decrease hardhat version to ~ 2.13.1, hardhat toolbox ~2.0.2.

I tried these steps and code ethers.getSigners() work well:
Update: 
```
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.13.1"
```
Remove all dependencies and re-run `npm install`

Comment: Thank you, will try this step today. :-)

Comment: Thanks the code 'ethers.getSigners()' works like a charm now :-).  I continued on with the rest of the code, and I now get an error message: " ReferenceError: waffle is not defined" the code snippet is: const mainnetForkProvider = waffle.provider;    I thought Waffle is installed part of the the hardhat tool-box. any ideas on this please.

Comment: Let's try ethers.provider for instead